# How to return a relative URI Location header with Flask?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

Flask replaces the content of my Location header when building my HTTP response.
It change my actual relative URI Location header with an absolute one.

```
@app.route('/votes', methods=['POST'])
def votes():
    return jsonify(), 201, {'location': '/votes/1'}
```

my test :

```
def test_vote_creation(self):
    response = self.app.post('/votes',
                             data=json.dumps({
                                 'name': 'Test vote'
                             }), content_type='application/json')
    print(response.headers['location'])
```

return `http://localhost/votes/1` instead of `/votes/1`

**How to return a relative URI Location header with Flask jsonify ?**

Edit: According to the current version of the HTTP/1.1 standard, RFC 2616, the value of the Location header must be [an absolute URI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.30).
But the RCF is going to change to allow relative URIs as well. So I want to change the default behaviour of my API to answer with a relative URI in my location header.

more detail on [this post](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/31274/what-are-the-consequences-for-using-relative-location-headers#31337)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? Sorry your post is not very clear to me at least

Comment: @codegeek I edited my question, I hope this is clearer

Comment: This is discussed in this [werkzeug issue](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/1859) on Github.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [HTTP RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) specifies that the `Location` header **must** be an absolute URI:

> #### 14.30 Location
>
> The Location response-header field is used to redirect the recipient
>   to a location other than the Request-URI for completion of the request
>   or identification of a new resource. For 201 (Created) responses, the
>   Location is that of the new resource which was created by the request.
>   For 3xx responses, the location SHOULD indicate the server's preferred
>   URI for automatic redirection to the resource. The field value
>   consists of a single absolute URI.
>
> ```
> Location       = "Location" ":" absoluteURI
> ```

As such the Flask / Werkzeug response object converts any relative URL `Location` header to an an absolute URL.

You *can* override this behaviour, although I would not recommend you do so. To override it, set the [`autocorrect_location_header` attribute of a `Response` object](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/wrappers/#werkzeug.wrappers.BaseResponse.autocorrect_location_header) to `False`. `jsonify()` returns a response object, alter that:

```
@app.route('/votes', methods=['POST'])
def votes():
    response = jsonify()
    response.status_code = 201
    response.headers['location'] = '/votes/1'
    response.autocorrect_location_header = False
    return response
```

but note that your WSGI server can still enforce an absolute URL even if Flask doesn't.

Comment: Thank you @martijn-pieters for the explanation. I know for the RFC. I just want to know if there is a solution, because the RFC is going to change. But for now I will change my frontend to handle absolute URI.

Comment: @martijn-pieters as of writing this comment, location doesn't need to be absolute. > The syntax of the Location header field has been changed to allow all URI references, including relative references and fragments, along with some clarifications as to when use of fragments would not be appropriate. ([Section 7.1.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.2)) - Source Page 92

Comment: @cianmce So I assume that the current answer is "not yet supported by Flask"?

Comment: Here is the updated RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231 -- it allows for a relative path.